# Transmission line loss

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

Let us suppose that a transmission line is carrying power to a resistor $R$
The resistor $R$ requires a power of $P=IV$.

Applying the most simple case where a transmission line is supplying a current $I$. The Ohmic loss is $P_c=I^2R_c$ for the cable.

Putting $I=P/V$

$P_c=(P^2/V^2)R_c$
So to decrease Ohmic loss we need to increase $V$
but this is the potential difference across the resistor, right? I have read other questions here, but it still doesn't make sense. Please help.

What my textbook says

> Consider a resistor R to which a power P is to be delivered via a transmission cable having res. $R_c$ to be dissipated finally. If $V$ is voltage across $R$ and $I$ the current then
>
> $P=VI$
>
> The connecting wires from the power station to the resistor has res. $R_c$. The Ohmic loss is $P_c=I^2R_c$
>
> $P_c=(P^2/V^2)R_c$
>
> Thus to drive a device with $P$ the power wasted in the connecting wires is inversely proportional to $V^2$.

A few paragraphs later...

> The  transmission cables from power stations are hundreds of miles long and their resistance $R_c$ is considerable. To reduce $P_c$, these wires carry current at enormous values of $V$

Comment: This is a duplicate in that the voltage $V$ is ill defined and it is this lack of clarity which causes the ambiguity. Have a read of https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/248233/104696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to decrease Ohmic loss we need to increase V but this is the potential difference across the resistor, right?

One option is to transmit the power over long distances at high voltage, then use a transformer near the load to reduce the voltage to whatever is required by the load.

For example, power may be transmitted across continents at 100's of kV, then reduced by a sequence of transformers to 110 or 220 V to power your home.

If your power source is DC rather than AC, then you could use a switching converter to do something similar. You'd first want to evaluate whether it's cheaper to include that switching converter in your system, or just use a larger diameter wire to reduce the $R_c$ term.

Comment: I agree, but my textbook mentions that since we increase $V$. The Ohmic loss is reduced in the cable, which I don't think is true as $V$ is meant for the resistor

Comment: Without seeing exactly what your textbook says, I can only guess what's meant. Maybe they meant increase V and (load) R both so that the same power is delivered?

Comment: They made $R$ constant so yeah

Comment: Maybe they just meant increase V by $I R_c$ so that the load gets the voltage that was originally intended? Including a complete quote (with context) from your book into your question might make things more clear.

Comment: I think it would be an error?

Comment: @DaivyaJadeja, I'm not going to say it's an error if you don't share the exact quote with enough context to make clear what they meant.

Comment: "Consider a device R to which a power P is delivered via transmission cables having res. $R_c$ to be dissipated finally .

Comment: @DaivyaJadeja, please edit your question to include all the information needed to answer it.

Comment: Just a minute..

Comment: The text you quoted doesn't say anything about increasing V to reduce loss.  It just says power loss is proportional to $1/V^2$.  And the sentence that says it says P is fixed, not R. I don't see any error there.

Comment: But then increasing $V$ shouldn' affect the power loss in the cables as they are independent?

Comment: For a fixed resistive load, it will increase the power lost in the line, because the line loss is $I^2 R_c$ and I will be increased by increasing V

Comment: Unless, like I said in my answer, you can increase the transmission voltage without increasing the voltage at the load.

Comment: Edited once more

Comment: My answer already addresses that. They use transformers near the load to reduce the voltage before delivering power to the load.

Answer (score -1):

The V in Ohm's law is the voltage drop across the load.

You are trying to reduce the voltage drop and so the power lost along the line.

Comment: the load includes the wires and the resistor?

Comment: This is a very common error, but I don't see where OP made it.  They carefully distinguished $R_c$ (line resistance) from $R$ (load resistance).

Comment: @ThePhoton, all 'V' are really dV, there are two dV's the one along the transmission lone and the one across the load. Or if you prefer there is a single I and two R's and P = I^2 R

Comment: @MartinBeckett, I still don't see where OP made any mistake. They consistently used $V$ to be the voltage across the load and never used it where they should have used the voltage across the line.

Comment: @ThePhoton, the only 'losses' are across the line if we assume the load at the end is all useful work. If you ignore voltage drop along the line then there is no benefit in a high voltage, power is just =IV. If you want to increase efficency then the higher voltage allows a lower current in the line (where the P=IV is wasted) for the same P=IV at the load, that is why losses are reduced by V^2

Comment: @MartinBeckett, the losses are due to the resistance of the line. But OP has written a correct expression for those losses without using a term for the voltage across the line (hint: they wrote the current through the line in terms of the power and voltage delivered to the load). So your answer does not address what they were asking about.