# I have a doubt regarding the supply of power to cities, through transformers

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electrical-resistance, power

***I=Current, V=Potential Difference, R=Resistance, P=Power(just in case if you don't understand wth I am speaking)***

I understand the contradiction between P=VI and Ohm's Law, and I understand about Transformers too, but, my only problem is that, I don't get the idea, **how exactly does all of this happen?**
I mean, look, V inverses to I in calculating power supply, but, why use it, when we already know a relation(R=V/I, as the current travels through electric cables, which undoubtedly possess resistance, so should be able to calculate I), and it only makes it harder to understand, I mean, I watched numerous vids, and googled the stuff, but none of the answers seems to satisfy me, I am looking for a suitable answer that makes me say, "Woah, that was some fire!"

I mean I get so confused, while transferring the power, V inverses to I, but as soon as the same current passes through the step-down Transformer, and gets to the household circuits, it's back to Ohm's Law again(let's assume there are only ohmic conductors), I mean, when I try to co-relate the two, and try to understand this whole massive setup of **"transferring power from power plant to houses**," I am unable to understand all of this practically, and reading the book doesn:t help me, though I might not have read it so carefully.

I Am In 10th Standard, so simple, answers are very very welcome, though I will try my level best to understand the higher level answers as well

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"I understand the contradiction between P=VI and Ohm's Law"* What contradiction? *"V inverses to I in calculating power supply"* What does that mean?

Comment: Umm, I don't quite understand, I mean, isn't that a contradiction that, in Ohm's Law, V is directly proportional to I to get the same resistance, while, in P=VI, If we increase V, I must be decreased, to get the same power output, i mean, I know that, P and R are obviously different things, but i Said that just to highlight the relation between V nad I in the two cases

Comment: By saying, V inverses to I in calculating power, I meant that, in P=VI, if we increase V, I should be decreased accordingly, to ensure we get the proper Power output
I SIMPLY MEANT IT MATHEMATICALLY, PLEASE HELP ME IN THAT REGARD TOO, IF I AM MISSING OUT ON SOMETHING

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High voltage power lines - clarification of energy loss](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248229/high-voltage-power-lines-clarification-of-energy-loss)

Comment: Please reduce your use of capital letters. Expressing a sentence in all capitals is considered on the internet to be the equivalent of shouting in face to face communication. Hopefully, you wouldn't shout to ask your question in person, so please don't "shout" to ask your question here.

Comment: Ok buddy, sooo thanks, you told me this fact, I didn't know about this, actually, I am newbie here, that's why, thanks, your help is greatly appreciated 

Answer (score 0):

I imagin a small community using just 200kW of power at 200V
with $200,000W=V*I$ you have $I=1000A$ so the resistance of all the stuff is $R=0.1\Omega$ so if the the voltage at the beginning would be 200V too and the wire to the community had resistance $R_w=1\Omega$  the current would be $200V/1,1\Omega=182A$ instead of 1000A and your power would be V=18V.
so you should be happy to have a transformer increasing the Voltage in the wire 100 times, so the current in the wire ist only 1/100 of the former.
You should not only consider $P=V*I \text{ but also } P=I^2*R  or P=V^2/R$.
Maybe you can ask your teacher to do an Experiment with 6 V lamp and a wire to the lamp with some resistance larger than the one of the lamp , and then transform the voltage at the beginning to 100V and at the end to 6 V again. than you can really "experience the difference in classroom.

Comment: I wish my teachers were that good, all they do is scold you for not knowing certain concept, and leave you in depression