# Does $P=VI$ contradict $V=IR$?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

Imagine there's a dam generating power (P) that needs to be transported 100km away. Engineer Pedro suggests increasing the voltage to reduce current acording to P=VI, while Engineer Juan suggests decreasing the voltage to achieve the same effect, considering the cable’s resistance and OHM law (V=IR). Which engineer is incorrect, and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High voltage power lines - clarification of energy loss](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248229/)

Comment: Hmm voltage is created before the current or the power

Comment: Comparing P=VI to V=IR is comparing apples to oranges. One is power. The other is voltage. If you want to compare power loss, then you need to compare power loss, not something else.